# Application to do regular expression search on all pages linked to some specified html page

Tags: search, regex, web

I am using a Windows 8 machine and starting with an html page I would like to automatically retrieve the text content from every link on that page that matches a regex. The retrieved content must then be searched for another regex and any matches listed in a table along side the URL from which the match was found.

Currently I am just searching through each URL individually using the Browser search box.

I cannot see any way of doing this with the tools available in any Browsers. I know I could write a script but I figure there may be an application (or a script someone else has written) that does this already.

Comment: It's hard to believe that there is a ready made application that does exactly this. Please rather just ask about what you need to accomplish. Also, it would be good to mention your operating system and what you've already tried.

Comment: Has this question violated some policy? Why the down vote?

Comment: We expect questions to show some effort into finding a solution, including your attempts (see [ask]). Also, it's not clear what your OS is, so any answer would be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Today I feel as your [Mechanical Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk), so I wrote some lines of bash script.

Get all links in a $MAINPAGE:

```
wget $MAINPAGE -O - | sed 's%<a%\n&%g' | sed 's%.*href=["\']%["\'].*%'
```

Loop through them and search for the regex:

```
for LINK in $(wget $MAINPAGE -O - | sed 's%<a%\n&%g' | sed 's%.*href=["\']%["\'].*%'); do
  # abort grepping after first match and return the
  # count (number of matches, which is then 0 or 1),
  # if count > 0 then print the LINK url.
  if [ $(wget $LINK -O - | grep -c -m 1 -e 'I_AM_A_REGEX') -gt 0 ]; then
    echo $LINK
  fi
done
```

PS: *Untested!*